# How do I get blender to leverage all the memory I have?

Tags: memory-management

There are probably so many noob-facets to this question that it's not even funny. Basically I've never fully understood memory usage, despite being a professional digital artist for many years.

In this case, I'm trying to make sure that Blender is using as much memory as I can give it. My computer has an absurdly large amount of RAM, well over 64 gigs. I've gotten the impression that this is "overkill", but I definitely find Blender slowing down when I do high-poly sculpting, or when I apply complex modifiers.

I've set the Memory Cache Limit to the maximum, 32768 mb, but I'm wondering if there's some other obvious thing I should be doing to leverage the massive amount of memory that I have available. Or maybe the things I'm trying to do are more dependent on the CPU or other factors? I'm running Windows 10, if that matters, and I've got a 64-bit version of Blender.

Comment: What are the specs on your graphics card? If it doesn't have enough memory, it won't be able to update the screen fast enough to avoid lagging.

Comment: Also memory is not the only meter for performance of your computer, there are other components responsible, namely the graphics card (for drawing and screen updates) like Scott mentioned, and the processor speed. For sculpting the processor is likely to be the larger bottleneck. There are also software limitations and inefficiencies to consider, no matter how fast your computer may be, the software can only go as fast as the programmers are able code it to.

Comment: Having large amounts of ram will allow you to work with larger/more complex geometry or more complex scenes(more vertices or larger textures),it will give you the capability to pre-fecth larger videos, but is the CPU and the GPU that do the computing work.